# How to change a variable inside subroutine?

Tags: perl, scope

The following code

```
use strict;

my $var = new();
foreach (1..3){
        print $var->{val},"\t",$var->{inc}(),"\n";
    }

sub new{
    my $foo = 0;
    return {
        val => $foo,
        inc => sub {
                   # do something with $foo
                   $foo++;
                   }
    };
}
```

gave output:

```
0    0
0    1
0    2
```

So we can't change `$foo` inside subroutine `$var{inc}` by setting up `$var{val}`. Is there any way to do this? It's likely that one `my $foo` variable split into two different entities in the same scope (?) What is going on with `my $foo` in this program in terms of scope and duration?

Comment: Why not using function also to read variable, `val => sub { $foo }`

Comment: Think about what is said in the `perlref`: _Closure is not something that most Perl programmers need trouble themselves about to begin with._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to store a reference to $foo in the hashref, i.e. `val => \$foo`.  Currently you're storing just the value, so it won't be updated.

Be sure to dereference it when accessing, i.e. `print ${$var->{val}}`